# Using darkice as a service at startup

Tags: boot, services

I am trying to setup a Raspberry Pi to stream to Broadcastify using Darkice.

I have followed the setup process outlined on this [website](https://sites.google.com/site/glyman3home/raspi-streaming-to-broadcastify):

The issue I'm currently facing is that I cannot get the service to work.

In `/etc/init.d/darkice1` I have:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/darkice1 

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          darkice1
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Simple script to start a program at boot
# Description:       A simple script to start and stop darkice
### END INIT INFO

# If you want a command to always run, put it here

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "START"    
    if [ ! -f /etc/darkice1.cfg ]; then
    echo "Configuration file /etc/darkice1.cfg not found! Darkice not started... "
    exit 1
    fi
    echo "Starting darkice Instance #1"
    /usr/bin/darkice
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping darkice Instance #1"
    pkill -f darkice1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/darkice1 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

When I run `$ sudo service darkice1 start` it doesn't seem like the service is actually starting... I'm not seeing any of the output in the command line. Am I just totally misunderstanding how services work?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the Jessie version of the OS, the proper command should be:

`sudo /etc/init.d/darkice1 start`

The other code is deprecated in this version of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Raspbian Stretch` and in its default repository I find `darkice` with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list *darkice*
```

So there is no need to follow outdated instructions. Simply install `darkice` and use it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install darkice
```

Then you can start and stop it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop darkice.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start darkice.service
```